# Outer container 'null' not found.

Tags: containers, outer-join

used jssor slider ,  i have some pages with same jssor slider , some pages are working fine , but some pages comes Outer container 'null' not found.   bug , can any one help on this ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, so did some digging to see what the issue was.

The setup starts with the initial call, here's the snippet from the demo site
http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

which, among setting up all kinds of utility functions- more importantly does this

```
    function JssorSlider(elmt, options) {
        var _SelfSlider = this;

        ... 
        // bunch of other functions
        ...

        $JssorDebug$.$Execute(function () {
            var outerContainerElmt = $Jssor$.$GetElement(elmt);

            if (!outerContainerElmt)
                $JssorDebug$.$Fail("Outer container '" + elmt + "' not found.");
        });
    }
```

so at this point, it's trying to collect the string you passed, which is the elmt variable- which is for what? Well let's take a look at that $GetElement function in jssor.js

```
    _This.$GetElement = function (elmt) {
    if (_This.$IsString(elmt)) {

        elmt = document.getElementById(elmt);
    }

    return elmt;
};
```

So, really, what it comes down to is this line for finding the element.

```
elmt = document.getElementById(elmt);
```

So the base of this error is 
"We tried to use your string to find a matching ID tag on the page and it didn't give us a valid value"

This could be a typo, or another line of code modifying/removing the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are some scripts try to remove or modify element in your page.

Please right click on your page and click 'Inspect Element' menu item in the context menu.
Check if the 'outer container' is still there in the document. And check if there is another element with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Slider1_Container" is present or Used.
In my case, I didn't have it in my html, but still I had added the js.
Removing js resolved my issue.